# Grounding of a Metal Roof Vent

Tags: roof, grounding, vent

My kitchen range hood is vented through the roof. The vent pipe on the roof is made of metal and extends a bit higher than the roof ridge. It is connected via metal ducts to the range hood. The range hood itself is grounded.

Do I need to ground the vent pipe on the roof?

I live in the US (New York).

Comment: For what purpose? Lightning protection?

Comment: How are the duct pieces held together?

Comment: Is the vent in close proximity to a power feed? If not I can't see it being needed.

Comment: @threephaseeel with metal screws.

Comment: @isherwood that's the first (and so far only) thing that comes to my mind. Would it make sense though?